# When should I call javax.jdo.Query.close(Object) and Persistence Manager in JDO?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdo, datanucleus

I have an old project where I used JDO to fetch the data from Datastore. I have the following code

```
    public List<User> findAll() {

        LOGGER.info("Getting users list");
        Query query = null;
        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        try {
            query = pm.newQuery(User.class);
            List<User> user = (List<User>) query.execute();
            return user;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error while getting user list", e);
            return Collections.emptyList();
        } finally {
            if(query != null) query.closeAll();
            pm.close();
        }
    }
```

I am calling the above method from my service and when I try to process the result, I am getting an error as

> javax.jdo.JDOUserException: Query result has been closed

I tried to copy the result set to new list and return it but it also didn't work.

```
List<User> user = (List<User>) query.execute();
return new ArrayList<>(user);
```

How can I solve the issue? Shouldn't we have to close the query and pm ?

Comment: you can put the stacktrace for more information please

Comment: The result collection from a QUERY is bound to the database. If you close the query and want to access that collection, an exception is thrown. The solution you pointed out should work (it's the one i use). Ex: Collection col=new ArrayList(query. execute())

Comment: Also, don't create a local collection, and then a new one to encapsulate the first! (this will cost you a lot of resources with huge collections...)

Answer (score 0):

You can test this code :

```
  public List<User> findAll() {
    LOGGER.info("Getting users list");
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();        
    Query query  = pm.newQuery(User.class);
    try {
        return (List<User>) query.execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error while getting user list", e);
        return Collections.emptyList();
    } finally {
        query.closeAll();
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's the same as mine.

Comment: You can put the stacktrace please ?

Comment: It won't work, because the result collection from a QUERY is bound to the database. If you close the query and want to access that collection, an exception is thrown. The solution is to return new ArrayList(query. execute())